# How to get an image url given term_image_tid using the customfield-PHP views module

Tags: views, 6

I have created a view of type Term that lists all the taxonomy terms plus each term's image. This works. But now I want to wrap the images in a link that links to another view. I am trying to use the `customfield: PHP Code` field to build up an html string containing the image and the link. The only bit that I cant figure out is how to get the url of the image.

If i do `print_r( $data);` I get...

```
stdClass Object ( [tid] => 7 
[term_data_name] => Old Edinburgh 
[term_data_vid] => 2 
[term_image_tid] => 7 )
```

And the sql query is...

```
SELECT DISTINCT(term_data.tid) AS tid,
   term_data.name AS term_data_name,
   term_data.vid AS term_data_vid,
   term_image.tid AS term_image_tid
 FROM term_data term_data 
 LEFT JOIN term_node term_node ON term_data.tid = term_node.tid
 INNER JOIN node node_term_node ON term_node.vid = node_term_node.vid
 LEFT JOIN term_image term_image ON term_data.tid = term_image.tid
  GROUP BY tid
```

Answer (score 0):

You [shouldn't use a PHP code field](https://ohthehugemanatee.org/blog/2013/12/26/44497-people-are-wrong-how-to-never-use-views-php/), rather you can use the [Image URL formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter) module to create a image URL field, exclude it from display, & then use that image URL field to feed into a `Global: Custom text` field with your own custom `img` & `a` markup.

Comment: Hi, thanks but this is Drupal 7 only.